# ModelJUnit Run Test for a period of time

Tags: java, testing, junit, model, automated-tests

I am performing some model-based testing on an application system, and I want to execute my tests for a specified duration of time (let's say for 15 minutes).

How can I achieve this, please?

So far, my tester looks like this:

```
final Tester tester = new GreedyTester(new AgentSystemModelTests());
tester.setRandom(new Random());
tester.buildGraph();
tester.addListener(new StopOnFailureListener());
tester.addListener("verbose");
tester.addCoverageMetric(new TransitionPairCoverage());
tester.addCoverageMetric(new StateCoverage());
tester.addCoverageMetric(new ActionCoverage());
tester.generate(500);
tester.printCoverage();
```

Comment: Explain a bit more why you want to run for 15 minutes instead of running a certain number of tests. Can you just have a while loop that runs for 15 minutes and calls tester.generate(100) maybe?

Comment: @tkruse I have a number of tests that I would like to run continuously for 15 minutes, what I did was `tester.generate(50000000);` this way I got the test to run for 15minutes, but I just wanted to see if maybe there is a more efficient and better way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tester.generate(int n)`  is defined in the `Tester` class as being a loop run for `n` times calling `generate()`.

To run the tests for a set amount of time, consider using a `while` loop set to stop as soon as the time has passed, something like the following.

```
final Duration TEST_DURATION = Duration.ofMinutes(15);

final Instant startTime = Instant.now();
final Instant finishTime = startTime.plus(TEST_DURATION);

final Tester tester = new GreedyTester(new AgentSystemModelTests());
tester.setRandom(new Random());
tester.buildGraph();
tester.addListener(new StopOnFailureListener());
tester.addListener("verbose");
tester.addCoverageMetric(new TransitionPairCoverage());
tester.addCoverageMetric(new StateCoverage());
tester.addCoverageMetric(new ActionCoverage());

// This is the magic predicate for the loop
while (Instant.now().isBefore(finishTime)) {
   tester.generate();
}
tester.printCoverage();
```

Sources:

[Tester.java](https://sourceforge.net/p/modeljunit/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/modeljunit/src/main/java/nz/ac/waikato/modeljunit/Tester.java)

[GreedyTester.java which inherits RandomTester.java which inherits Tester.java](https://sourceforge.net/p/modeljunit/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/modeljunit/src/main/java/nz/ac/waikato/modeljunit/GreedyTester.java)